# email arrival notifier

Tags: email, notifications

How can I get an alert in my local system when I got a mail even though I haven't signed in?

Comment: What type of e-mail account? POP? IMAP? GMail?

Comment: which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use Microsoft Outlook or any desktop mail client that supprts mail alerts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GMail on Windows- http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html